# $0=a \cos (\phi + b) +c \cos (\phi +d)$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find the maximum for a problem in continuum mechanics involving a 2D stress tensor. Now I arrived at a point where:

$0 = a \cos \left( \phi + b \right) + c \cos \left( \phi + d \right)$

My constants are $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. For which $\phi$ does the right side of the equation become $0$?

As a note on the side: The equation that I really want to solve is:

$0= \left(\sigma_y-\sigma_x\right)\cos\left(2\phi-\arctan \frac{1}{\mu} \right)+2\tau_{xy}\cos\left(2\phi-\arctan\mu\right)$

I'd be happy if someone could point me into the right direction. I've not found a fitting identity equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the addition formula $\cos(\phi+b)=\cos\phi\cos b-\sin\phi\sin b$ then rearrange to get $p\cos\phi=q\sin\phi$.  Then your answer is an arctangent.